# Creating a Shiny App for Fantasy Football Draft Optimization

Tags: r, optimization, shiny, linear-programming

I've written some R code to produce the optimal fantasy football lineup (maximize projected points scored) constrained on user inputted roster sizes and draft budget based on a data frame called "players" that consists of player, position, fantasy points, and draft value.

The idea is to use this tool prior to drafting (to have the ideal lineup in mind) and then to update it live while drafting since this never goes to plan.

From there, I want to be able to remove players from the players dataset (when they're drafted by others) and add players to my lineup as I draft them (so they appear in every future optimal lineup). I have added the functionality and th remove player button seems to work fairly well (for some reason the lineup vanishes when you input a new player each time, but then re-appears properly once a new player is removed) but it definitely doesn't seem to draft a player to the team properly. I'm definitely thinking it has something to do with the last snippet of code before running the app, but I'm having trouble thinking through the logic there.

The dataframe is:

```
players <- structure(list(Player = c("Josh Allen", "Patrick Mahomes", "Justin Herbert", 
"Lamar Jackson", "Kyler Murray", "Jalen Hurts", "Tom Brady", 
"Dak Prescott", "Joe Burrow", "Russell Wilson", "Aaron Rodgers", 
"Trey Lance", "Matthew Stafford", "Kirk Cousins", "Derek Carr", 
"Tua Tagovailoa", "Justin Fields", "Trevor Lawrence", "Ryan Tannehill", 
"Daniel Jones", "Matt Ryan", "Jameis Winston", "Carson Wentz", 
"Mac Jones", "Jared Goff", "Zach Wilson", "Davis Mills", "Baker Mayfield", 
"Marcus Mariota", "Deshaun Watson", "Mitchell Trubisky", "Geno Smith", 
"Drew Lock", "Kenny Pickett", "Jacoby Brissett", "Desmond Ridder", 
"Travis Kelce", "Mark Andrews", "Kyle Pitts", "Darren Waller", 
"George Kittle", "Dalton Schultz", "T.J. Hockenson", "Dallas Goedert", 
"Zach Ertz", "Dawson Knox", "Hunter Henry", "Mike Gesicki", "Pat Freiermuth", 
"Cole Kmet", "Irv Smith Jr.", "Noah Fant", "Tyler Higbee", "David Njoku", 
"Albert Okwuegbunam", "Gerald Everett", "Robert Tonyan", "Jonathan Taylor", 
"Christian McCaffrey", "Derrick Henry", "Austin Ekeler", "Dalvin Cook", 
"Joe Mixon", "Najee Harris", "Alvin Kamara", "D'Andre Swift", 
"Leonard Fournette", "Saquon Barkley", "Aaron Jones", "Nick Chubb", 
"James Conner", "Javonte Williams", "Ezekiel Elliott", "David Montgomery", 
"Cam Akers", "Travis Etienne Jr.", "Breece Hall", "J.K. Dobbins", 
"Josh Jacobs", "Antonio Gibson", "Elijah Mitchell", "AJ Dillon", 
"Cordarrelle Patterson", "Damien Harris", "Miles Sanders", "Clyde Edwards-Helaire", 
"Tony Pollard", "Devin Singletary", "Kareem Hunt", "Chase Edmonds", 
"Rashaad Penny", "Rhamondre Stevenson", "Kenneth Walker III", 
"Melvin Gordon III", "Darrell Henderson Jr.", "James Robinson", 
"James Cook", "Dameon Pierce", "Michael Carter", "Jamaal Williams", 
"Nyheim Hines", "J.D. McKissic", "Kenneth Gainwell", "Alexander Mattison", 
"Isaiah Spiller", "Raheem Mostert", "Mark Ingram II", "Marlon Mack", 
"Brian Robinson", "Gus Edwards", "Rex Burkhead", "Rachaad White", 
"Khalil Herbert", "Damien Williams", "Tyler Allgeier", "D'Onta Foreman", 
"Jerick McKinnon", "Cooper Kupp", "Justin Jefferson", "Ja'Marr Chase", 
"Davante Adams", "Stefon Diggs", "Deebo Samuel", "CeeDee Lamb", 
"Mike Evans", "Tyreek Hill", "Tee Higgins", "Keenan Allen", "DJ Moore", 
"A.J. Brown", "Michael Pittman Jr.", "Mike Williams", "Brandin Cooks", 
"Jaylen Waddle", "Diontae Johnson", "Terry McLaurin", "DK Metcalf", 
"Courtland Sutton", "Amon-Ra St. Brown", "Darnell Mooney", "Allen Robinson II", 
"Marquise Brown", "Amari Cooper", "Gabriel Davis", "Chris Godwin", 
"Michael Thomas", "Jerry Jeudy", "Adam Thielen", "JuJu Smith-Schuster", 
"Hunter Renfrow", "Rashod Bateman", "Elijah Moore", "Tyler Lockett", 
"Christian Kirk", "Robert Woods", "DeVonta Smith", "Drake London", 
"Allen Lazard", "Brandon Aiyuk", "Chase Claypool", "Kadarius Toney", 
"Tyler Boyd", "Garrett Wilson", "DeVante Parker", "Chris Olave", 
"Kenny Golladay", "Jakobi Meyers", "Russell Gage", "Marquez Valdes-Scantling", 
"DeAndre Hopkins", "Marvin Jones Jr.", "Treylon Burks", "Michael Gallup", 
"Robbie Anderson", "DJ Chark", "Jahan Dotson", "Mecole Hardman"
), Position = c("QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR"), FantasyPoints = c(445, 410, 407, 348, 
351, 359, 354, 364, 402, 368, 353, 347, 349, 335, 366, 325, 297, 
313, 273, 283, 302, 284, 275, 296, 291, 0, 247, 286, 276, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 269, 0, 0, 252, 231, 206, 171, 185, 177, 174, 169, 169, 
171, 139, 131, 170, 170, 162, 129, 162, 119, 130, 126, 130, 340, 
285, 260, 278, 277, 271, 277, 247, 271, 225, 247, 249, 230, 196, 
268, 205, 199, 213, 231, 220, 177, 176, 159, 178, 185, 155, 181, 
157, 190, 177, 164, 156, 166, 169, 179, 158, 129, 147, 99, 158, 
176, 150, 100, 157, 128, 156, 124, 98, 95, 75, 90, 136, 80, 82, 
143, 128, 0, 147, 97, 63, 326, 337, 308, 299, 269, 267, 271, 
242, 243, 241, 239, 243, 242, 244, 209, 220, 233, 239, 221, 198, 
221, 209, 220, 209, 218, 178, 224, 183, 186, 203, 188, 164, 207, 
211, 202, 173, 188, 163, 199, 171, 181, 182, 140, 170, 175, 144, 
142, 164, 147, 131, 170, 160, 182, 136, 153, 157, 152, 148, 175, 
144), DraftValue = c(31, 23, 20, 15, 16, 14, 16, 11, 12, 10, 
10, 3, 7, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 37, 34, 22, 20, 17, 16, 12, 11, 9, 6, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 56, 55, 44, 48, 38, 38, 40, 38, 36, 
34, 34, 33, 27, 30, 28, 27, 23, 21, 23, 21, 19, 18, 10, 15, 16, 
16, 12, 12, 14, 13, 10, 11, 12, 8, 9, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 56, 48, 41, 
40, 37, 31, 34, 29, 30, 28, 28, 26, 24, 26, 23, 23, 22, 21, 20, 
18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 17, 15, 15, 17, 17, 16, 16, 15, 15, 13, 12, 
12, 12, 11, 9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-177L))
```

and the code is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(lpSolve)
library(rsconnect)

# Define the UI for the app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Fantasy Football Lineup Optimizer"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("num_qb", "Enter the number of QBs:", 1, min = 1, max = 5),
      numericInput("num_rb", "Enter the number of RBs:", 2, min = 1, max = 5),
      numericInput("num_wr", "Enter the number of WRs:", 3, min = 1, max = 5),
      numericInput("num_te", "Enter the number of TEs:", 1, min = 1, max = 5),
      numericInput("num_value", "Enter your draft budget:", 200),
      numericInput("num_players", "Adding in your flex spots, enter the total number of starters:", 9, min = 1, max = 15),
      selectInput("remove", "Remove a player:", choices = c("",as.character(players$Player)), multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("update", "Update Team"),
      selectInput("draft", "Draft Player", choices = c("",as.character(players$Player)), multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("draft_button", "Draft")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("team")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  players <- players
  
  # Create a new column indicating the player's position
  players$QB <- ifelse(players$Position == "QB", 1, 0)
  players$RB <- ifelse(players$Position == "RB", 1, 0)
  players$WR <- ifelse(players$Position == "WR", 1, 0)
  players$TE <- ifelse(players$Position == "TE", 1, 0)
  players$Total <- 1
  rv <- reactiveValues(players=players)
  
  # Define the objective function (maximize fantasy points)
  obj <- players$FantasyPoints
  
  # Define the constraints (position limits and draft value limit)
  con <- reactive({
    matrix(c(
        # QB constraint
        rv$players$QB,
        # RB constraint
        rv$players$RB,
        # WR constraint
        rv$players$WR,
        # TE constraint
        rv$players$TE,
        # Draft value constraint
        rv$players$DraftValue,
        #Total players constraint
        rv$players$Total
    ), ncol = nrow(rv$players), byrow = TRUE)
})

  
  # Define the variables for the lp
  dir <- c("<=", rep(">=",3),"<=","<=")
  
  # Define the initial optimal lineup
  initialLineup <- reactive({
    rhs <- reactive({
      c(input$num_qb, input$num_rb, input$num_wr, input$num_te, input$num_value, input$num_players)
    })
    result <- lp("max", obj, con(), dir, rhs(), all.bin = TRUE)
    rv$players[result$solution == 1,]
  })
  
    # Show the updated optimal team in a table for any constraint change
  output$team <- renderTable({
    lineupResult()[, c("Player", "Position", "DraftValue", "FantasyPoints")]
  })
  
  # Define the function to run when the "update" button is pressed
  updateLineup <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    removedPlayer <- input$remove
    rv$players <- rv$players[rv$players$Player != removedPlayer,]
    obj <- rv$players$FantasyPoints
    rhs <- reactive({
      c(input$num_qb, input$num_rb, input$num_wr, input$num_te, input$num_value, input$num_players)
    })
    result <- lp("max", obj, con(), dir, rhs(), all.bin = TRUE)
    rv$players[result$solution == 1,]
    
  })
  
  # Define the function to run when the "draft player" button is pressed
  draftPlayer <- eventReactive(input$draft, {
    draftedPlayer <- input$draft_player
    draftedPlayers <- rv$players[rv$players$Player == draftedPlayer,]
    rv$players <- rv$players[rv$players$Player != draftedPlayer,]
    rv$draftedPlayers <- rbind(rv$draftedPlayers, draftedPlayers)
    rhs <- reactive({
    c(input$num_qb, input$num_rb, input$num_wr, input$num_te, input$num_value, input$num_players)
    })
    result <- lp("max", obj, con(), dir, rhs(), all.bin = TRUE)
    rv$players[result$solution == 1,]
    rv$players <- rbind(rv$players, rv$draftedPlayers)
    })
  
  
  # Show the updated optimal team in a table when the "update" button is pressed
    output$team <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$draft_player)) {
    if (is.null(input$remove)) {
    initialLineup()[, c("Player", "Position", "FantasyPoints", "DraftValue")]
    } else {
    updateLineup()[, c("Player", "Position", "FantasyPoints", "DraftValue")]
    }
    } else {
    draftPlayer()[, c("Player", "Position", "FantasyPoints", "DraftValue")]
    }
    })
    }


# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave this one a shot. I modified your code quite a bit to reduce some of the complexity to it but first I'll point out a few issues I saw before I rewrote portions of it.

The reason why your lineup vanishes and then re-appears at times is due to how you link up your `renderTable` to your inputs and eventReactives.

`output$team` has dependencies on `input$draft_player` and `input$remove`. First off I don't see `input$draft_player` in your UI so I assume this is meant to be `input$draft_button`. With that said, when removing a player, the renderTable function invalidates first when you enter a player into the select input. But `updateLineup()` is dependent on `input$update` so it doesn't return anything until you click "Update Team". Thus causing the delay.

In your `draftPlayer` expression you haven't set `obj` to be the new value of `rv$players$FantasyPoints` so instead `lp()` takes the value of obj in the parent environment which has the full set of players and thus err's out.

One additional thing I noticed is in both functions you return `rv$players[result$solution == 1,]`. Personally, I think the problem with this is you'll always output the most optimized full lineup regardless of your own draft selections. Intuitively, I would think you'd want to return the best lineup not including the positions you've already drafted. So if a QB and 2 WR's have been drafted. Then you'd return a lineup with only 6 players since 3 have already been drafted.

Below, I've written some code that takes that last piece into account as well as reduce the number of output functions. This is just what made sense to me and maybe I'm off base here, but hopefully it's along the same lines of what you're trying to accomplish!

Let me know if you have any questions.

The goal with the code below, is to include your draft picks alongside the optimized selection. When a player is drafted, we need to do a few things.

1. remove the player from the pool
2. update `const.rhs` with new constraints

- subtract the position requirement by 1
- subtract the overall number of players by 1
- subtract the draft budget by the players draftValue

When a player is removed they are simply 'removed' from the player pool and `lp` will run without that player.

With the new constraints in place, `lp` will return a new lineup with the number of available players and positions that have yet to be drafted using a modified draft budget. After a player has been drafted or removed, they will be removed from the select inputs so you can't accidentally choose them in the future.

#### Restrictions

In my version I have a few constraints to be aware of. For simplicity sake, you can only remove or draft one player at a time. Due to how `const.rhs` is calculated, the sum of the position inputs MUST match the total number of starters. I know that could be an issue as after the 5 or 6th round, I'll debate on whether to pick up an RB or WR depending on who's available. Also I would advise not changing any input above remove player once the draft has started since that will likely screw things up.

#### App Code

```
library(shiny)
library(lpSolve)
library(purrr)

# Define the UI for the app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Fantasy Football Lineup Optimizer"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("num_qb", "Enter the number of QBs:", 1, min = 1, max = 5),
      numericInput("num_rb", "Enter the number of RBs:", 3, min = 1, max = 5),
      numericInput("num_wr", "Enter the number of WRs:", 3, min = 1, max = 5),
      numericInput("num_te", "Enter the number of TEs:", 2, min = 1, max = 5),
      numericInput("num_value", "Enter your draft budget:", 200),
      numericInput("num_players", "Adding in your flex spots, enter the total number of starters:", 9, min = 1, max = 15),
      selectInput("remove", "Remove a player:", choices = c("",as.character(players$Player)), multiple = FALSE),
      selectInput("draft_player", "Draft Player", choices = c("",as.character(players$Player)), multiple = FALSE),
      actionButton("update", "Update Lineup")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("team")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  players <- players

  # New col to indicate if a player has been drafted
  players$Drafted = "No"

  # Create a new column indicating the player's position
  players$QB <- ifelse(players$Position == "QB", 1, 0)
  players$RB <- ifelse(players$Position == "RB", 1, 0)
  players$WR <- ifelse(players$Position == "WR", 1, 0)
  players$TE <- ifelse(players$Position == "TE", 1, 0)
  players$Total <- 1
  rv <- reactiveValues(players=players)

  # Set up reactive table for lineup output
  updateLineup = reactiveVal(NULL)

  # Define the objective function (maximize fantasy points)
  obj <- players$FantasyPoints

  # Define the constraints (position limits and draft value limit)
  con <- reactive({
    matrix(c(
        # QB constraint
        rv$players$QB,
        # RB constraint
        rv$players$RB,
        # WR constraint
        rv$players$WR,
        # TE constraint
        rv$players$TE,
        # Draft value constraint
        rv$players$DraftValue,
        #Total players constraint
        rv$players$Total
    ), ncol = nrow(rv$players), byrow = TRUE)
  })

  # Define the variables for the lp
  dir <- c("<=", rep(">=",3),"<=","<=")

  # Define initial 'const.rhs'
  init_rhs <- reactive({
    list(
      QB = input$num_qb,
      RB = input$num_rb,
      WR = input$num_wr,
      TE = input$num_te,
      n_val = input$num_value,
      n_players = input$num_players
    )
  })

  # Define reactive 'const.rhs'
  rhs = reactiveValues(const = list())

  # Run once to get the initial values and set them to reactiveValues
  # so they can be changed later
  observeEvent(init_rhs(),{
    rhs$const = init_rhs()
  }, once = TRUE)

  # Define the initial optimal lineup
  initialLineup <- reactive({
    result <- lp("max", obj, con(), dir, init_rhs(), all.bin = TRUE)
    rv$players[result$solution == 1,]
  })

  # Define the function to run when the "update" button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    # Remove player here
    if(input$remove != "") {
      removedPlayer <- input$remove
      rv$players <- rv$players[rv$players$Player != removedPlayer,]
      obj <- rv$players$FantasyPoints
    }

    # Draft player
    if(input$draft_player != "") {
      draftedPlayer <- input$draft_player
      draftedPlayer_details <- rv$players[rv$players$Player == draftedPlayer,]
      draftedPlayer_details$Drafted = "Yes"
      rv$players <- rv$players[rv$players$Player != draftedPlayer,]
      rv$draftedPlayers <- rbind(rv$draftedPlayers, draftedPlayer_details)
      obj <- rv$players$FantasyPoints # missing object

      # Subtract constraints: position and n_players by 1 and draft budget by the players 'DraftValue'
      # Necessary so "result" outputs a table with the remaining positions left
      # otherwise it will return an entirely new lineup
      rhs$const = purrr::imap(rhs$const, function(cs, nm) {
        if(nm == draftedPlayer_details$Position) {cs = cs - 1}
        if(nm == "n_players") {cs = cs - 1}
        if(nm == "n_val") {cs = cs - draftedPlayer_details$DraftValue}
        return(cs)
      })
    }

    # Update select inputs to remove players after "Update Lineup" is clicked
    if(input$remove != "" || input$draft_player != "") {
      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "remove", choices = c("",rv$players), selected = "")
      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "draft_player", choices = c("",rv$players), selected = "")
    }

    # Define result with updated arguments
    result <- lp("max", obj, con(), dir, rhs$const, all.bin = TRUE)
    # Assign new table to the reactiveVal 'updateLineup'
    updateLineup(rbind(rv$draftedPlayers, rv$players[result$solution == 1,]))
  })

  output$team <- renderTable({
    if (input$update == 0) {
      initialLineup()[, c("Player", "Position", "FantasyPoints", "DraftValue", "Drafted")]
    } else {
      updateLineup()[, c("Player", "Position", "FantasyPoints", "DraftValue", "Drafted")]
    }
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you, this helps so much! it's definitely a major step forward but I'm seeing two bugs that I can't seem to answer. When "update lineup" is pressed, it resets the optimal lineup to 9 players with this code. So, if I open the app and change the lineup constraints to 8 in total (1 qb, 2 rb, 2 wr, 1 te, 2 flex) and draft friermuth, it shows me a lineup with 9 players INCLUDING another TE. Even though I'm drafting a player from the optimal lineup when I draft friermuth, it changes the optimal lineup to including a TE by default, even though I already have the one i need.

Comment: i think this is because I didn't mention the "flex" constraint initially, so i apologize for that. I was building in the flex requirement with the total roster size constraint. So, total roster size would be greater than the sum of the qb+rb+wr+te in the amount of your flex constraint, which is admittedly a poor design.

Comment: I'm a bit busy this week but will look into it by next week if I can't get to it sooner. I can fix the issue that inadvertently forces the output to 9 players. The flex constraint is a bit trickier

Comment: I added another post for this problem specifically with another bounty - just to make sure you were aware to get that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75520219/adding-a-flex-position-in-a-fantasy-football-lineup-optimizer